# How to convert a city/state to a geo location (lat/long) using bing?

Tags: geolocation, bing

How to convert a city/state to a geo location (lat/long) using bing?

Comment: In what language / environment?

Comment: using the javascript sdk

Answer (score 3):

This example uses Yahoo's API but gets the job done for me. Will work if you just submit a zipcode or city,state. I use a dataset because I'm addicted to them.

```
private void YahooParseLatLon(string address_)
{
HttpWebRequest feed =
HttpWebRequest.Create("http://local.yahooapis.com/MapsService/V1/geocode?
appid=YOUR_APID&street=" + address_) as HttpWebRequest;

WebResponse feedresponse = default(WebResponse);
feedresponse = feed.GetResponse();
DataSet data = new DataSet();
data.ReadXml(feedresponse.GetResponseStream());
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Address"))) {
//process lat lon values
string lat = data.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Latitude");
string lon = data.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Longitude");
}
else {
//process no address found
}
data.Dispose();
feedresponse = null;
feed = null;
}
```

I use this to collect lat/lon for addresses on new orders placed in my company's system. I then use this data to populate a map integrated into a scheduling application for our field agents.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [geotag generator](http://geotags.com/geo/) use can use.

Comment: page not fount /404

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [complete tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427601.aspx) on MSDN to do what you are looking for.

Note you want to make sure you are linking to **7.0** and NOT **6.3**.